# How to provide values (...), (...), ... with Spring's JDBCTemplate effectively?

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

I want to provide a `values (...), (...), ...` to a query. How can this be done with Spring's `JDBCTemplate`?

Example query:

```
with
bookings(date, start_time, end_time, room) as
(
    values ('2015-01-01'::date, '10:00'::time, '11:00'::time, 'office a'),
           ('2015-01-01'::date, '12:00'::time, '17:00'::time, 'office a'),
           ('2015-01-02'::date, '12:00'::time, '17:00'::time, 'meeting')
)
select * from bookings
```

I cannot find out how to bind the non-fixed list of values to one or multiple parameters dynamically. In the example, I have three rows, but I want to support any number of rows.

**update**

The related question does not really solve my question. I am not doing a batch update. I am providing a dynamic table via `values (...), (...), ...` to a CTE clause which I can use in the rest of the CTE query.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inserting multiple rows using JdbcTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3165730/inserting-multiple-rows-using-jdbctemplate)

Comment: @eis I added an edit to explain that this not solve my question. Thanks though!

Comment: ah. retracted the close vote. That's probably not explicitly supported - you may need to just generate the SQL string dynamically and use jdbctemplate based on that.

Comment: Ah, that sucks. You know any useful Java SQL libraries which I could use? I still want to use plain SQL (so no Hibernte/ORM), but I want to avoid creating SQL strings dynamically all over the place.